# Error codes when trying to connect chatGPT api

Tags: python, prompt, chatgpt-api

What is causing these return self._post and self._request ? Is this purely a rate limit issue? what's the best way to go about it? upgrade to paid plan? I'm new, any feedback would be tremendously helpful.
I tried to feed chatGPTPrompt to analysis a list of numbers, I was expecting it to print the analysis.

```
    def BasicGeneration(userPrompt):
        completion = client.chat.completions.create(model ="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages=[
            {"role": "user", "content": userPrompt}])
        return completion.choices[0].message.content
 chatGPTPrompt = f""" please provide an analysis of these prices, here's the price list: {prices}"""
```

PS B:\VSCode> python test.py

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "B:\VSCode\test.py", line 55, in <module>
    analysis = BasicGeneration(chatGPTPrompt)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "B:\VSCode\test.py", line 9, in BasicGeneration
    completion = client.chat.completions.create(model ="gpt-3.5-turbo",`
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sonder2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\openai\_utils\_utils.py", line 303, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sonder2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\openai\resources\chat\completions.py", line 604, in create
    return self._post(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sonder2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\openai\_base_client.py", line 1088, in post
    return cast(ResponseT, self.request(cast_to, opts, stream=stream, stream_cls=stream_cls))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sonder2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\openai\_base_client.py", line 853, in request
    return self._request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sonder2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\openai\_base_client.py", line 916, in _request
    return self._retry_request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sonder2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\openai\_base_client.py", line 958, in _retry_request
    return self._request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sonder2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\openai\_base_client.py", line 916, in _request
    return self._retry_request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sonder2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\openai\_base_client.py", line 958, in _retry_request
    return self._request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sonder2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\openai\_base_client.py", line 930, in _request
    raise self._make_status_error_from_response(err.response) from None
openai.RateLimitError: Error code: 429 - {'error': {'message': 'You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details. For more information on this error, read the docs: https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/error-codes/api-errors.', 'type': 'insufficient_quota', 'param': None, 'code': 'insufficient_quota'}}`](https://stackoverflow.com)
```

Comment: The error is "You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details", so I guess you need to check your plan and billing details.

Answer (score 0):

In the OpenAI there is an option of changing increase limit, which can help to resolve this issue
[image]